# Expressing outrage

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, english-to-latin-translation

I'm looking for a way to express in Latin "she broke a blood-vessel in a fit of passion".

It's an English idiom, not to be taken literally, but used to express a burst of outrage or anger. I need something idiomatic, if such a thing exists, rather than a clumsy-looking direct translation.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valentinian apparently literally burst a blood vessel after an angry outburst, dying of a stroke.

Ammianus Marcellinus describes how Valentinian ***ictu sanguinis exstinguitur*** after angrily berating envoys of the Quadi (*History*, XXX.6).  Perhaps this could suit your purpose.

Alternatively, the furious Valentinian is described as being ***ira vehementi perculsus*** (XXX.6.3)

Comment: Thank you: exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! I know Ammianus basically as one of Gibbon's major souces, but I've read nothing of his for myself and would not have thought to look there. [If you know 'Rip Van Winkle', it is to describe the demise of his Dame.]

Answer (score 1):

Dido goes a bit off the rails at the end of [Aeneid IV](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0055%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D450)

> In dreams she feels cruel Aeneas goad her madness on,/ 
>   and ever seems she, friendless and alone,/ 
>   some lengthening path to travel, or to seek/ 
>   her Tyrians through wide wastes of barren lands./ 
>   Thus frantic Pentheus flees the stern array /
>   of the Eumenides, and thinks to see/ 
>   two noonday lights blaze oer his doubled Thebes;/ 
>   or murdered Agamemnon's haunted son,/
>   Orestes, flees his mother's phantom scourge/ 
>   of flames and serpents foul, while at his door 
>   avenging horrors wait. 
>   *Vergil. Aeneid. tr. Theodore C. Williams*

From that passage, are any of these three useful?

"mad, as if she sees the columns of the Eumenides":

> *Eumenidum veluti demens videt agmina.*

"agitated by visions":

> *agitatus scaenis.*

"Avenging horrors sit upon the doorstep":

> *ultrices sedent in limine Dirae.*

Comment: Thank you: an interesting reminder indeed, but not quite apposite